# Fast thermal ramp up/ power efficiency

Tags: power, resistors, heat, thermal, peltier

I want to build a controlled temperature well in an alumminum block, and right now I am in doub as to what heating method choose. I am mostly torn between a high power resistor such as [this](http://pt.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/RH050150R0FC02/?qs=oFi4/QsgZXYdykWTBf8Cwn8R2/shRA70) or thermoelectric coolers/heaters easily available on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5PCS-OF-12V-6A-72W-TEC1-12706-Thermoelectric-Cooler-Cooling-Peltier-Plate-Module-/380672780985?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item58a1ddaab9).

My primary concerns are in the way heat is distributed across a 4x4cm aluminium cube (I need it as uniform as possible) and power consumption - I gather I would need large currents in both cases, but which would be most efficient with a 12V DC PSU?

Comment: What about induction heating? I know it's aluminium but at 2 or 3 MHz it should get warm. How hot does it need to get?

Comment: Aluminum is used in heatsinks because it has a very high specific heat, which reduces the temperature rise for a given energy input. (Also, it's very cheap and easy to shape.) But its thermal conductivity is relatively poor. If you are interested in fast transient response and good uniformity, you should be using copper instead. Its higher thermal conductivity and lower specific heat will both be advantageous. For best results, use diamond, but that tends to be expensive in the size you're talking about.

Comment: I am trying to build something similar to this:http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-PCR-thermal-cycler-for-under-85/step2/Materials/, so it would need to be able to get from ambient to 100ºC (not necessarily fast, but as fast as possible while keeping temperature uniform). They use aluminium though.

Comment: @Andyaka wouldn't induction heating require more complex components? That would have the disavantage of being more expensive.

Comment: @joaocandre So your primary concern may actually be cost rather than the way heat is distributed?

Comment: @Andyaka a good compromise between the two would be more precise, which is why induction heating might be a bit overkill.

Comment: Oscillator, small power amp capable of running at a couple of MHz, two or three turn coil and tuning capacitor.

Comment: -1 for asking an incomplete question. You implied that your criteria were uniformity, efficiency and transient response (more or less in that order), which is what I addressed, but now it seems that you also have concerns about complexity and cost. Also, you need to start quantifying your requirements; vague phrases like "as uniform as possible", "as fast as possible" and "most efficient" tell us nothing at all about your specific application. If you have a budget limit, tell us what it is.

Comment: If you can, mill the block into a cylinder.  That way, each edge will have the same thickness.  Working with a cube for uniform heating makes things so much more difficult.

Comment: @Andyaka If that's all it takes, it is indeed an interest solution. However, that would lead to a more complex circuit - what would be the advantage over TECs or Resistors?

Comment: possibly a more evenly spread input of heat directly at the surface if the block. The only thing being heated is the block. You can shape the induction coils to suit the shape. Disadvantage is the unknown re how much input power is needed and how high the freq would be to minimize penetration to maximize best use of skin effect. Resistors are almost self explanatory of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to heat the block, you'd be far better using resistors than TECs (cheap, and you can use whatever number/configuration of them you need to get suitable uniformity.)

PCR cyclers use TECs because they want to cool quickly as well as heat.

There's no efficiency issue, because all the 'waste' ends up as heat anyway, which is what you wanted in the first place.  Once you've delivered the electricity to the heater, it's 100% efficient, regardless of its construction.

Update: Thought I'd better add that if you're entertaining some idea of using the TECs as a heat pump to give you extra heat by cooling the outside world, don't bother.  Every configuration of TECs is disappointing, but that one will be particularly so.

Comment: In fact, the possibility of also using the TECs as a cooling device is also atractive (I am considering using a standard CPU heatsink to cool the whole thing). But as @Andyaka suggested, eletromagnetic induction might also be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need heating, resistors would likely be your cheapest approach, and you may wish to prototype with that method to see what power level you need. If the temperature or the watt density (watts per unit area) are too high, or the uniformity is inadequate, you could use another approach.

You could attach a copper block to the side of the aluminum block with swaged cartridge heaters inserted into the Cu block. That would allow you to get to hundreds of watts per square inch with good uniformity.

If the required watt density is lower, one method I would suggest is to use a [polymide (Kapton) heater](http://www.minco.com/Heaters/~/media/WWW/Resource%20Library/Heaters/Polyimide%20Thermofoil%20Heater%20Tech%20Spec.ashx) bonded to a face of the aluminum block. Minco is a supplier of such, there are others.

[image]

[image]

Try to use a something away from the maximum watt density range for maximum reliability.

[image]

Comment: I've come across Kapton films and was indeed also considering them an option. But what exactly are the implications of the watt density on heating/cooling performance? On another note, which of these solutions would have a faster "cool down"?

Comment: The less thermal mass in the heater, the faster it will cool down. High watt density means the heater will get hotter than otherwise, and the life will be reduced, also (especially with non-film heaters) the control will tend more to overshoot.

Comment: Would a custom cut "serpent" shaped film from Kapton/polyimide tape like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/321368048505?var=510257056772&ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649 achieve the same end result as Minco's Kapton heaters?